# openldap: add auxiliary class

Tags: ldap

I want to add an auxiliary class to OpenLDAP. What exactly do I have to do?

I'm using Apache Directory Studio as editor.

I've added a new core schema with olcObjectClasses "testclass" and an olcAttribute "company".

This worked fine.

But when I add this auxiliary class to an inetOrgPerson Object and add the new attribute defined in my class, the Apache Directory Studio says that this attribute wasn't allowed. Nevertheless I can add it.

Are some auxiliary classes restricted by the inetOrgPerson or is there any dependency between classes? Is it sufficient to define a new schema, a testclass and an olcAttribute? I defined them similar to the inetOrgPerson entries. Are there any "meta-entries" where new entries have to be defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sufficient to add the attributes mentioned. Needless question.